# Rally Application Manager support for Java/Ruby/C# Toolkit?

Tags: rally

Is there any documentation or examples on using API keys with Rally Ruby toolkit? Also, are the other Rally toolkit (Java,C#) supported for use with API keys? (https://help.rallydev.com/rally-application-manager). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Ruby example [here](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/ruby-rest-apps/blob/master/change_pi_state.rb). Replace `config[:username]` and `config[:password]` with `config[:api_key]`

```
config[:api_key] = "_abc123"
```

Currently only [rally-node](https://github.com/RallyTools/rally-node) and [ruby](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby) toolkits support API Key, but eventually the others should too.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611977/select-user-stories-based-on-feature-using-rally-api) has a  rally-node example that uses API Key.

Comment: is it possible to create a API key with a subset of privileges allowed for a rally account?

Comment: Just so we know and can it to the team that did the api keys - what subset of privileges are you interested in seeing?